# Very basic java program doesnt run

Tags: java

So I am a java newb, started last week and have been reading a book. In the book at the end of a chapter it gives a challenge to make a program that will output

```
*
**
***
```

I am trying to get it so that it outputs is the number of lines as args (That is correct right?). The issue i am having is it the program will only output a page of asterisks as in:

```
***************...
```

The code is

```
        public class Rektifier {

public static void main(String[] args) {

    int Lines = 1; // amount of lines i want

    int stars = 0; //asterisk i want

    int X = 0; //Counter for the asterisks for loop

        while (Lines <= Integer.parseInt(args[0])){ //I think I found this on stack overflow, it is to search through the arguments for integers
            Lines =+ 1; // increase by 1 for the while loop

            stars =+ 1; // do this to increase by 1 for the amount of stars i want, could be any number

                for (X = 0; X >= stars; X =+ 1){ // forloop, if x is less than stars it should add * to the end of the line. Then increase x by 1 to add another star until x is equal to star then it should continue
                    System.out.print("*");
                }
            System.out.println(); //creates a new line to add on too
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: you assign `1` to `Lines` and `Stars` and `X` with each iteration. it should be `+=` or `Lines++` or `++Lines`, but `Lines =+ 1` will just assign `1` here.

Comment: Also change `X >= stars` to `X <= stars`

Comment: and also make 'X' and 'Line' L in small case. Java follow camel case.

Comment: Java follow camel case?

Comment: http://www.javatpoint.com/java-naming-conventions Yes

Comment: and use println instead of print since you want the stars to be in 3 lines , and not in 1 line right?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have two loops. The **outer** `while()` loop uses `Lines` as its control variable. This loop decides **how many stars** are to be printed in each line – therefore `Lines` should take the values: 1, then 2, then 3, etc... (as for now it does not due to a small typo: so you should replace `Lines=+1` with `Lines+=1`)
Your **inner** `for` loop uses `X` as its control variable. This loop **actually prints the number of stars** dictated by the `Lines` variable, so you should correct it to the form: 
`for (X = 0; X < Lines; X++)`
Your variable `stars` is not necessary in such case.
*(btw. refrain from starting variable names with capital letters; this works perfectly but is against tradition)*.

Answer (score 0):

Or you can simply use `for` loops. You have nested 2 iterations. `For` loop is better for this case. Use `while` when execution count depends on some mutable condition.

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {
            int lines = 3;
            // lines loop
            for(int i=0; i<lines; i++){
                // stars loop
                for(int j=0; j<=i; j++) {
                    System.out.print("*");
                }
                System.out.println();
            }
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

For this easy learning example you could do string operation to get the result you want

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    int lineCount = Integer.parseInt(args[0]));
    String stars = "";
    for (int index = 0; index < lineCount; ++index) {
        stars += "*";
        System.out.println(stars);
    }
}
```

This will produce the following output for arg = 10:

```
*
**
***
****
*****
******
*******
********
*********
**********
```

Every iteration the stars string will append a star to the existing stars.

Answer (score 0):

There's answers here but they aren't pointing out the actual bugs in your code. I'll point out the bugs in your code.  First and foremost:

What you need to do is first think of what the pseudocode looks like. It should look like this.

```
for (line_number ... number of lines):
   for(0...line_number)
      print star
   print newline.
```

Here's the bugs in your code with comments in the lines:

```
        public class Rektifier {

public static void main(String[] args) {

    int Lines = 1; 

    int stars = 0; //This is not useful. The number of stars will always be equal to the number of lines. Why not just use the number of lines?

    int X = 0; //Would rather that you utilize the for loop for declaring X, it is only used there.
        while (Lines <= Integer.parseInt(args[0])){ 
            Lines =+ 1; // Increment at the end of the while loop. Otherwise, you print two stars on the first line.

            stars =+ 1; // Again not used.

                for (X = 0; X >= stars; X =+ 1){ // your for loop is wrong; it reads like this. for x = 0 and x is bigger than stars, do blah. then you don't actually increment X because it should be X += 1 not X =+ 1.
                    System.out.print("*");
                }
            System.out.println(); //creates a new line to add on too
        }
    }
}
```

Here's a working implementation of your code using the same structure you are using.

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    int lines = 1;
    while (lines <= Integer.parseInt(args[0])){ 
        for (int x = 0; x < lines; x += 1){ 
            System.out.print("*");
        }
        lines += 1;
        System.out.println();
    }
}
```